# Android web-based Emulator Manymo, how does it work?

Tags: android, android-emulator, html5-canvas, emulation

I was looking for an **online emulator for Android** and I found this: https://www.manymo.com

Most of android developer might be familiar with this or may be not, as its quit new in the market.

So as developer, first thought came in my mind is, **how it works** (many of you will think after checking this out).

My research: At front-end it is using Canvas, which is taking input from user and displaying response as an screen image. So front end is pretty clear to me.

Now at back-end I am not pretty sure, what technique they are using (regardless programming language or platform). What I think is they run a Emulator instance for each session on there server and some how they capture its screen and invoke input at certain places of screen.

**So the confusing part is, how they are sending inputs to Emulator and geting screen of emulator, at server side?**

Any clue will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems they are using [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) Client (see HTML Source).

On Server side they can use any Emulator with VNC Support.

Answer (score 1):

The inefficient-but-expedient solution is to use existing testing frameworks or their underlying engines, like ChimpChat.

The efficient-but-tedious solutions include:

- Hooking into **`qemu`**, the emulation engine that drives the Android emulator, and/or
- Running modified emulator images, with modify firmware, that enable this

Comment: Hooking qemu, something sounds meaningful. Modifying emulator seems confusing and difficult approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are sending inputs to emulator using monkeyrunner script.we have used monkeyrunner script for generating screenshots for one of our android application. but i don,t know which technique they are using to run emulator instance for each session because emulator required lots of CPU resource.